# Gitlab CI: How do I download a image before jobs start executing?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run jobs in multiple stages. Is it possible to download a image while previous stages are running & current stage execution has not started?

Answer (score 0):

Considering [jobs in the same stage](https://Jobs%20in%20the%20same%20stage%20run%20in%20parallel.) run in parallel, you can define a job using a [shell executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/shell.html) which will do a `docker pull`.

In the same stage, you can define other jobs which can execute parallel commands.

The next stage, executed on the same runner, will benefit from the docker image already downloaded.